# Do you need to fill out the MedXPress form every time you renew your medical?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

In the US, to get a 3rd-class medical certificate I know that you have to fill out this form on the FAA's website, get a confirmation number, then take that confirmation number to the medical examiner. My question is, do I have to do that every time? Or is the one confirmation number good forever?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each time you renew you will need to complete the medical history questionnaire on the MedXPress website and obtain a fresh confirmation number.